# Which one should I choose between collecting Flow from ViewModel or collecting Flow in Compose directly

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The code A collect Flow in `ViewModel,` and convert a Flow as hot Flow using `MutableStateFlow`, then use `collectAsState()` in Compose.

The code B collect Flow in Compose, and use `collectAsState` in Compose directly.

Which one is the better between code A and code B ?

In my mind, the code A convert a Flow as hot Flow in ViewModel, it will retain memeory and waster resources, is it a good way?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun BookListScreen(
    viewModel: BookListViewModel,
    ...
) {
    val booksListUiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    ...
}


@HiltViewModel
class BookListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val bookUseCase: BookUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    private var loadBooksJob: Job? = null
    
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(BookListUiState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        loadBooks()
    }

    fun loadBooks() {
        loadBooksJob?.cancel()
        loadBooksJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            bookUseCase.listBooks().collect { resultState ->
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(bookListState = resultState)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}


override fun loadBooks(): Flow<ResultState<List<Book>>> {
  ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(
    name: String,
    mViewMode:SoundViewModel= viewModel()
) {
    Column(
        
    ) {
     val myResult by mViewMode.listRecord().collectAsState(initial =Result.Error(Exception()) )

     ..
}


@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val aSoundMeter: RecordRepository
): ViewModel()
{
    fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {
        return  aSoundMeter.listRecord()
    }

}


@Dao
interface  RecordDao { 
    @Query("SELECT * FROM record_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
    fun listRecord():  Flow<List<RecordEntity>>
}



class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val mRecordDao:RecordDao): IRecordRepository {
    override fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {      
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Code A**, you're keeping a flow into the view model. Therefore, this flow will be saved in case of the user rotates the device. Also, the `loadBooks` will not be called in case of a recomposition in `BookListScreen`.

In **Code B**,  `listRecord` is called every time a recomposition happens, therefore every time the screen is redrawn you're doing a data base call. Since your DB is local, the damage does not look so bad, but if you're using a remote DB (like Firebase or REST web service) this code will perform a network call in every recomposition, including when you rotate the device or returning to this screen.

Check it out [this Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8GZWCbUm3tBXKeqIi3rcVX) from Android Developers Channel. In particular [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9VR8KbmzEE) (which is more focused in your problem).